# Will EASA approve single engine IFR commercial operations any time soon? Will this be a big impact on the industry?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, easa-regulations

I saw that discussions were going on for EASA to approve single engine turbine airplanes for IFR commercial operations. Anybody knows the current status? Where can I find it? Is it going ever to happen? Another question is how big impact this is going to make? Are SAT much more efficient and cheaper to run than multi engine aircraft?

Comment: What discussion?

Comment: By commercial do you mean passenger service? At least in the US (not sure about EU) there are quite a few single engine turbine planes approved for IFR commercial ops, typically for cargo missions (FedEx actually has quite a few).

Comment: Yes, passenger service